# I'm not able to auto hide server validation messages

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-validation

I'm able to show server validation messages but the problem is, as I'm using server validation, the validation messages are not hiding as it normally does when the user again starts filling individual inputs in client-side validation. How to hide them when the user starts typing in this case?

[image]

The component class:

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  public registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    firstname: [""],
    lastname: [""],
    email: [""],
    password: [""],
    password_confirmation: [""]
  });
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  errors = [];
  registerUser() {
    console.log(this.registrationForm);
    this.authService.registerUser(this.registrationForm.value).subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => {
        this.errors = err.error.message;
        console.log(this);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The Form:

```html
<div class="row pt-5">
  <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
    <div class="card rounded-0">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="mb-0">Register</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form
          class="form"
          (ngSubmit)="registerUser()"
          [formGroup]="registrationForm"
        >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Firstname</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              formControlName="firstname"
              name="firstname"
              class="form-control rounded-0"
              [class.is-invalid]="errors.firstname"
            />
            <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="errors.firstname">{{
              errors.firstname
            }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Lastname</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              formControlName="lastname"
              name="lastname"
              class="form-control rounded-0"
              [class.is-invalid]="errors.lastname"
            />
            <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="errors.lastname">{{
              errors.lastname
            }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              formControlName="email"
              name="email"
              class="form-control rounded-0"
              [class.is-invalid]="errors.email"
            />

            <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="errors.email">{{
              errors.email
            }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              formControlName="password"
              name="password"
              class="form-control rounded-0"
              [class.is-invalid]="
                errors.password
              "
            />
            <span class="invalid-feedback" [class.d-none]="errors.password">{{
              errors.password
            }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              formControlName="password_confirmation"
              name="password_confirmation"
              class="form-control rounded-0"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
              Register
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** I'm not using Angular's inbuilt validator, rather I want to implement the same using server-side validation.

Comment: You are not showing any code of how you are getting these server side errors. Apparently you store them in an `errors` variable, but how does that work? Apparently not an async validator either.

Comment: I'm not using async validator.. Rather these are validation message from a REST api.. I'm storing it into the errors property..

Answer (score 0):

Use keyup/down event of the input to change back the error to false in case of the email it will look like:

```
<input 
   // other properties ... 
   (keyup)="errors.email = false"/>
```

They it should work just fine.